# Android Studio: Cant change the color of my code (Code Scheme)

Tags: android-studio, colors, color-scheme

when i apply my downloaded scheme, the only thing it does is changing little parts of the code colors.
See the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eAv2.png)
But it should look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2pY9.png)

I really dont know what to do. Pls help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same sort of issue, you have to set a source root for it to recognize what kind of project it is.

[image]